# Perl Catalyst - Page not found when using href to link to page on the same site

Tags: html, perl, model-view-controller, controller, catalyst

I am creating a Catalyst application, currently I have a simple login page that also contains a 'Forgotten Password' link. It is all working perfectly, except when I click the 'Forgotten Password' link it should take me to a brand new html page that simply contains the words "Unlucky, you should have remembered it". Instead I get a 'Page not found' error.

**What I am doing:**

I have a Controller called **Login.pm** containing the following:

```
 sub default : Private {
    my ( $self, $c ) = @_;
    $c->forward('login');
 }

 sub login : Path('/login') {   
    my ( $self, $c ) = @_;

    $c->stash->{title} = "Login page";
    $c->stash->{page} = "html";
    $c->stash->{template} = "login.html";
 }
```

All of the above works correctly and produces the login page.

In the Catalyst root/**login.html** file (along with all the other bits like buttons) I have the following piece of code that should allow me to link to the 'Forgotten Password' html page.

```
<p><a href="forgotpassword.html">Forgot Password?</a></p>
```

The root/**forgotpassword.html** file it is referencing contains the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Unlucky, you should have remembered it</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

**However, when I click the 'Forgotten Password' link on the login page it goes to 'mydomainname/forgotpassword.html' and says 'Page not found'.**

Do I need to create a Controller for the forgotpassword page? and if so what would it need to contain? Or is there something obvious I am overlooking?

I am new to Catalyst.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally worked out the issue, thanks to 'mikew' for referring me to the 'Serving static content' section of the cookbook on CPAN.

**What the problem was:**

Using the html5 code below I was referencing a simple **html** page that required no interaction with Catalyst to work.

```
<p><a href="forgotpassword.html">Forgot Password?</a></p>
```

However, as mentioned in the [Cookbook](https://metacpan.org/module/ETHER/Catalyst-Manual-5.9007/lib/Catalyst/Manual/Cookbook.pod#Serving-static-content) and [Catalyst::Plugin::Static::Simple](https://metacpan.org/module/Catalyst%3a%3aPlugin%3a%3aStatic%3a%3aSimple)

**"By default, the following extensions are not served (that is, they will be processed by Catalyst): tmpl, tt, tt2, html, xhtml."**

and

**"There are some file types you may not wish to serve as static files. Most important in this category are your raw template files. By default, files with the extensions tmpl, tt, tt2, html, and xhtml will be ignored by Static::Simple in the interest of security."**

To prevent the 'Page not found' error (as the html page is ignored by default) you need to do add the following to the **MyApp.pm** file ensuring that you remove the extension/s you do not want to be ignored (in my case html files).

```
MyApp->config(
       static => {
           ignore_extensions => [
               qw/tmpl tt tt2 xhtml/
           ],
       },
 );
```

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for adding your detailed solution. I upvoted. If you can accept your own answer you should

Comment: No problems, thanks for your help. Will do, have to wait a day to be able to upvote your own answer though, thanks

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you want to do is make sure that file is served up statically. Look at the [cookbook](https://metacpan.org/module/ETHER/Catalyst-Manual-5.9007/lib/Catalyst/Manual/Cookbook.pod#Serving-static-content) for making sure you are configured to serve up static files instead of sending that request through catalyst.

Comment: thanks, your reference helped a lot, see my answer for the solution.